# Updating labels after button click

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var myLabel : UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(theButton: UIButton) {
    println(theButton.titleLabel!.text!)
    myLabel.text = " Hello"
}

}
```

I have a button and a and label on the Storyboard. A link is going from the View Controller to the label, and from the button to the View Controller. This code compiles but the text of the label is not updated. Thoughts?

Comment: How did you create the IBAction? Did you CTRL drag to the .swift file?

Comment: No, I copied and pasted from the Apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your IBOutlet needs to have weak in front of it

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
```

Your code is correct.  Just ran it fine.  So beyond this, I would check your links to your IBOutlet and your IBAction.

Some simple things to check are:

1. Next to `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction` there should be little circles to the left of the lines.  These circles should be filled in.  If they are not, then they are not linked correctly.  To link them, view the storyboard and the swift file side by side, and ctrl drag from the label or button to the outlet or action respectively.
2. In storyboard, hold down ctrl and click the label.  You should see `myLabel - View Controller` with a filled-in circle to the right. Now hold down ctrl and click the button.  You should see `Touch Up Inside - View Controller buttonTapped:` with a filled-in circle to the right.

Comment: I edited my answer to show the checks.  Your descriptions are right, but there could be a problem with them still.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the connection between your IBAction and the button isn't valid, so follow these steps to create your own.

1. Open your project. Look for these buttons: 
   [image: Step 1] Click the double-circles.
2. This will open a second editor window. Navigate and open your ViewController file and the Interface Builder file.
3. Press "Control" and drag to the .swift file. A blue line should appear where your mouse is. Release.
4. You should see a new popup appear, with the first line saying "Connection". Change it from "Outlet" to "Action".
5. Give your action a name.
6. In the IBAction block, place `myLabel.text = "Your text here."`